# Display additional dialog when application is in upgrade mode

Tags: installshield, installshield-2010, installshield-2011, installshield-2009

I created a setup file which is working awesome.

Now whenever I rebuild an application without changing anything but Package Code is changed and then while I am going to install this version then a dialog will come "Upgrade Dialog" which ask me for upgrade an application.

Now in this situation I want to display an additional dialog created by me.

I am using the Insatllshield 2012 BASIC MSI project type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem.

There are two properties exist in Installshield named **"IS_MINOR_UPGRADE"** and **"IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE"**.

When there is a minor upgrade at that time **IS_MINOR_UPGRADE will set to 1**. And same for Major upgrade.

**So using these properties, I can recognize the Upgrade mode.**

Comment: Worked for me.  Used 
"Not (IS_MINOR_UPGRADE OR IS_MAJOR_UPGRADE)"
in my condition to determine when we are not in an upgrade situation

Answer (score 0):

Any time you change the package code but not the product code you are talking about a Minor Upgrade or possibly a Small Update if you don't change the ProductVersion.  Either way,  the only way to create a custom message like you ask is to write your own setup.exe / update.exe bootstrapper to detect the update scenario and display your confirmation UI.

There's nothing built into MSI or IS that allows you to easily change this.